# How can I add a template class to ATL project?

Tags: c++, templates, com, atl

I am a beginner of COM (component object model) technology. Now I'm using ATL to build a com project in VS2013. I want to add a template class into the project using ATL wizard. But I don't know how. I did some search and find nothing about my question.

I am wondering if ATL support template class. If yes, could any one tell me how to add it?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You do not seem to understand what you are talking about. Grab a good C++ book and start reading.

Comment: I understand c++. What I'm talking about is COM.

Comment: Nope, you don't. Otherwise you would understand that your question does not make any sense.

Comment: It would be helpful if you can tell me where it does not make any sense.

Comment: @Danny Do you want to add a _class template_ or a templated class? ATL is all about template classes.

Comment: @Danny, your question is not unlike riddles from Alice in Wonderland. It's impossible to answer them. What do you mean by 'adding template class'? How can ATL (wich is just a library) support or prevent you from having a class of your own? Like I said, it does not make sense.

Comment: Sorry I didn't my question clear. Should I change it to how can I add a template class to ATL project?

Answer (score 0):

> I am wondering if ATL support template class. If yes, could any one tell me how to add it?

Yes, ATL supports template parameters (it's actually in the name *Active Template Library*) and you can build your own templated classes around these templates to aggregate things using meta programming techniques.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes I know the background of ATL is template classes which help us to build COM. I add ATL classes in VS2013 using ATL wizard. I didn't find any options there to let me add a template class. Could you give me some hint how to add template classes? Thank you again.

Comment: @Danny _"Could you give me some hint how to add template classes?"_ Just write the code. Are you actually asking for some wizard `dialog support?